# How do i display html/css/js on chromecast

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, chromecast

im trying to make a "infoscreen", and i want my chromecast to show relevant info like date, clock, weather etc...

I have made a Node.JS (Express) Application that makes a "screen" and displays all this data. I have tried to look into Google Chromecast recievers, but i can figure out a good way to use html/css/js instead of media files like mp4.

Is there a possibility to use html/css/js on chromecast?

i have a link for this screen here: https://im-infoscreen.herokuapp.com

Comment: Mhmm.. Most chrome browsers support cast, find your device and cast it?

Comment: Yes. That is what im doing, but then i need to have a browser open to display it. I want to do like for example Netflix, where you can start a casting and then close the app/tab

Comment: Browsers do support full-screen that puts the page into full-image. Your code would make this more netflix like, so it'd be up to you for that last part.